# How to sort table by date column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table and I want to sort Date column ascending and descending.

[image]

I have tried the code below but its not working. Its work when sorting the numbers only.

```
function sortColumn() {
        var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
        table = document.getElementById("example");
        switching = true;
        while (switching) {
            switching = false;
            rows = table.rows;
            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                shouldSwitch = false;
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[6];
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[6];
                if (parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > parseInt(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (shouldSwitch) {
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a lot to pick apart here. Firstly, `parseInt()` is going to take a String, like `"2"` and return the integer `2`. But it will not handle a string like `"13/09/2018"` since it's not just number characters. It's more work, yet you may consider harvesting the table data into an array of objects and then using sort tools to determine the sort order, then put the data back in it's new order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complex example than you might have been looking for. It makes use of the Array Sort function, which can make use of an optional `compareFunction` to perform the sort comparison.

```js
$(function() {
  function tableToArray(tObj) {
    var result = [];
    var keys = [];
    $("thead th", tObj).each(function(i, el) {
      keys.push($(el).text().trim());
    });
    $("tbody tr").each(function(i, row) {
      var temp = {};
      $.each(keys, function(j, k) {
        temp[k] = $("td", row).eq(j).text().trim();
      });
      result.push(temp);
    });
    return result;
  }

  function replaceTableData(tObj, data) {
    var b = $("tbody", tObj);
    b.html("");
    $.each(data, function(i, row) {
      var r = $("<tr>").appendTo(b);
      $.each(row, function(j, cell) {
        $("<td>").html(cell).appendTo(r);
      });
    });
  }

  function compare(a, b) {
    var dateA = a.Date;
    var dateB = b.Date;
    var result = 0;
    if (dateA > dateB) {
      result = 1;
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    return result;
  }

  function sortTable() {
    var tData = tableToArray($("table"));
    tData.sort(compare);
    replaceTableData($("table"), tData);
  }

  $(".sort-column").click(sortTable);

});
```

```css
.sort-column {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th class="sort-column" data-sort-order="null">Date</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>17/12/1989</td>
      <td>Homer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>07/09/2019</td>
      <td>Marge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>01/09/2019</td>
      <td>Bart</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>04/09/2019</td>
      <td>Lisa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>14/09/2019</td>
      <td>Maggie</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This sorts based on the text in the Date column. You could get more complex and parse the Date into a Date Object when you compare. But with this date format, it's not really needed.

**Update**

Moved code into function so it can be called in a Click event. This is a really simple example and if you need more complex actions, consider how that might work or DataTables.

Comment: If I want to sort the date column after clicking a button, how can I do that? Since the date column only sorted after this code, tData.sort(compare)

Comment: I tried to change the month and the year, but the code is only sorting for the date only

Comment: @Mary as I suggested, it's sorting on the text content of each character. As I mentioned if you want to compare them as Dates, you need to convert them into Date Objects.

Comment: Okay I will work on it. If my Date column is located at 7th column in the table, how can I specifically set for the above code?

Comment: @Mary this is binding to the click element of a specific class, `sort-column`. The Sort is working of the `Date` index. If it's not clear, I would suggest you update your OP with a more specific example.